# How do I keep a MySQL Fulltext Index up to date?

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

Creating an index MySQL

After I have added the FULLTEXT index, how do I keep it up to date?

Added it this way : `ALTER TABLE search_index ADD FULLTEXT(si_fulltext)`

Tried to update it like this :

```
ALTER TABLE search_index MODIFY FULLTEXT(si_fulltext)
ALTER TABLE search_index CHANGE FULLTEXT(si_fulltext)
```

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you disabled the index, the server should be keeping the index up to date as data changes in the column.  If you'd like to explore what is in the index, you can use  the `myisam_ftdump` utility:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-ftdump.html

Comment: Hi! sorry for the necro, but what do you mean by "as data changes in the column"? Does this include manual changes? like deleting a certain row and import a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It's updated automatically whenever data is inserted, updated or deleted form `search_index`.